# Recursive call - Action lambda

Tags: c#, recursion, delegates

What am I doing wrong here? How can I execute my action?

```
var recurse = new Action<IItem, Int32>((item, depth) =>
{
    if (item.Items.Count() > 0) recurse(item, depth + 1); // red squiggly here

    // ...
});
```

I'm getting a red squiggly when calling `recurse` saying *"method, delegate or event expected"*.

**Update**

I've accepted Homam's answer. I'd just like to add/share another syntax for the same... But which I find a bit easier on the eyes...

```
Action<IEnumerable<Item>> Recurse = null;

Recurse = item =>
{
    if (item.Items != null) Recurse(item.Items);

    // ...
};
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just define the delegate `Action` and assign null to it before calling it recursively.

```
Action<IItem, Int32> recurse = null;
```

Then

```
recurse = new Action<IItem, Int32>((item, depth ) =>
{
    if (item.Items.Count() > 0) recurse(item, depth + 1); // red squiggly here
    // ...
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: I'd hate to have to split definition and implementation. Is there any way I can do this in one line of code?

Comment: No.  Eric explains why in his blog entry (per usual it appears): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2006/08/18/706398.aspx

Comment: @Ron: Nice tidbit. Makes some sort of weird sense :)

Comment: There are ways to do anonymous recursion, such as defining a Y-Combinator, but this is much simpler.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wesdyer/archive/2007/02/02/anonymous-recursion-in-c.aspx

Comment: And the comments on Eric's blog have a fixed-point combinator that allows you to implement the lambda at the point of declaration, with no split.

Comment: Updated blog link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/why-does-a-recursive-lambda-cause-a-definite-assignment-error